# How can I attach the debugger of a .NET7 Application to a docker process on VS Code

Tags: .net, docker, macos, debugging

I am trying to debug a .NET 7 web api in VS Code that is running on a docker container. I tried setting the launch.json file to pick the remote process but I can't figure which process that I should attach to.

The launch.json was like that:

```
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}"
        }
```

Also, I tried specifying the debuggerPath but it seems that applications with .NET5+ shouldn't be done this way.

Anyone knows how can I debug this application?

EDIT 1:

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5211

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5211

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG configuration=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestDockerAttach/TestDockerAttach.csproj", "TestDockerAttach/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestDockerAttach/TestDockerAttach.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestDockerAttach"
RUN dotnet build "TestDockerAttach.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG configuration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "TestDockerAttach.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDockerAttach.dll"]
```

and the docker compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testdockerattach:
    image: testdockerattach
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestDockerAttach/Dockerfile
      args:
        - configuration=Debug
    ports:
      - 5211:5211
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    volumes:
      - ~/.vsdbg:/remote_debugger:rw
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux it is **dotnet** and on windows it will be **dotnet.exe** ref here: [Attach to a process running on a Docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-process-running-in-docker-container?view=vs-2022)

Comment: I'm getting no loaded symbols. I checked and the pdb is in the container but the issue continues